# Is Spark capable of processing data WITHOUT holding them in memory first?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I noticed that, for a simple job like this (read ORC data, write them out as is in parquet format):

```
val df = spark.read.option("basePath", "/projects/mydb/mytable").format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc").load("/projects/mydb/mytable/*")

val df2 = df.select("field1","field2","field3")

df2.write.option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2").format("parquet").save("/projects/outputfolder1/")
```

Spark takes a long time (and a lot of more resources) compared to hive (just an simply insert table select from...).

The Physical Plan looks nothing special, something like:

```
Execute InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand xxxx(source folder), false, format, Map(mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version -> 2, path -> xyz_path), Overwrite, [field1, field2, field3]
+- *(1) Project [field1, field2, field3]
   +- *(1) FileScan orc ...
```

Whilst observing how it works and play with different parameters (driver/executor memory, core, spark.sql.files.maxPartitionByte, etc.), it looks like Spark first will read the data into memory, then AFTER that, write it out. -- Is there a way to tell Spark just writes it out when it reads? (There is no need to really hold all the data in memory first in this case).

Thanks.

I am using Spark 2.4.4, hive 1.2.1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that a file to file copy always uses RAM, that is to say, I/O operations are (almost always) between a peripheral and RAM: 1) file --> RAM, 2) RAM --> file, it would imply that Spark must also use RAM for such an operation.

So, the short answer is No.

See this link also, btw: https://superuser.com/questions/988363/why-do-file-transfers-between-drives-use-ram

In short a general principle.

Comment: Do we know how Hive does that? For the same job, a simply hive "insert table select from..." for the same data, on the same cluster, is 5x more efficient than Spark (in terms of the job's total MB Seconds).

Comment: So, then use that. But that does not answer your own question.

Comment: Too bad, our use case is that, we want to move from hive to spark. That's why we identified for this use case, in which Spark is much worse than hive. :-)

Comment: But Hive also uses RAM, memory.

Comment: There's an overhead for starting and serializing and de-serializing.